# How to perform Internal censoring survival analysis in R

Tags: distributions, survival, modeling, censoring

I have data from 64 patients. These patients underwent a food challenge to elicit allergic reactions. I want to find the specific dose at which patient first had a reaction.

I am wondering how to create a data frame and perform survival analysis 
As I need to find out following two things
1) the lower dose (at which no reaction occurs) and 
2) the higher dose (when the first symptom appears) 
from this I will calculate the minimum dose which can cause the allergic reaction.
Data set look like this

```
patient ID  dose 1  event   dose 2  event   dose 3  event   dose 4  event
201        08:00      0     08:45    0       09:30   1      10:15    0
202        08:00      0     08:45    1       09:30   1      10:15    0
203        08:00      1     08:45    0       09:30   1      10:15    0
204        08:00      0     08:45    0       09:30   0      10:15    1
```

e.g., if a patient had a reaction at dose 3, then dose 2 will be the lower dose and 3 will be the higher dose.